# Using Panda to create new column with data from another row and column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create a new row for "new confirmed cases" using the current row 'confirmed' - yesterday 'confirmed'. Confirmed is cumulative.

my data is as shown

```
Country,Date,Confirmed,Deaths,Recovered,Active
China,2020-01-21,10,5,1,100
China,2020-01-22,20,10,2,104
China,2020-01-23,30,15,3,116 
France,2020-01-21,20,5,1,100
France,2020-01-22,30,10,2,118
France,2020-01-23,40,15,3,138
```

Output wanted

```
Country,Date,Confirmed,Deaths,Recovered,Active,New Confirmed
China,2020-01-21,10,5,1,100,0
China,2020-01-22,20,10,2,104,10
China,2020-01-23,30,15,3,116,10
France,2020-01-21,20,5,1,100,0
France,2020-01-22,30,10,2,118,10
France,2020-01-23,40,15,3,138,10
```

I know how to add a new row if using data from the same row but not sure how to use data from another row. Any tips or advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `shift()` method , `fillna()` method and `astype()` method:

```
df['New Confirmed']=df['Confirmed']-df['Confirmed'].shift(1).fillna(df['Confirmed']).astype(int)
```

Now If You print `df` you will get your desired output:

```
    Country     Date    Confirmed   Deaths  Recovered   Active  New Confirmed
0   China   2020-01-21  10          5       1           100     0
1   China   2020-01-22  20          10      2           104     10
2   China   2020-01-23  30          15      3           116     10
```

### Update:

For that condition use `groupby()` method,`shift()` method ,`fillna()` method and `astype()` method:

```
df['New Confirmed']=df['Confirmed']-df.groupby('Country')['Confirmed'].shift(1).fillna(df['Confirmed']).astype(int)
```

Output of above code:

```
    Country     Date    Confirmed   Deaths  Recovered   Active  New Confirmed
0   China   2020-01-21  10          5       1           100     0
1   China   2020-01-22  20          10      2           104     10
2   China   2020-01-23  30          15      3           116     10
3   France  2020-01-21  10          5       1           100     0
4   France  2020-01-22  20          10      2           104     10
5   France  2020-01-23  30          15      3           116     10
```